# Enable toggle music flutter using assets_audio_player package

Tags: flutter, dart

I use `assets_audio_player` package. I have a code in background and okey play music. My music doesn't repeat in background, how do I enable toggle music?

```js
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
    _assetsAudioPlayer.open(
      Audio('assets/sound/mafia-sound.mp3'),
      showNotification: true,
    );
  }
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player

Answer (score 0):

i fixed by code :)

```html
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
    _assetsAudioPlayer.loopMode.listen((loopMode){
      _assetsAudioPlayer.open(
        Playlist(
            audios: [
              Audio("assets/sound/mafia-sound.mp3"),
              Audio("assets/sound/mafia-sound.mp3")
            ]
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```